# Checksum returning same value for different sets

Tags: t-sql, duplicates, checksum

Curious why the SQL Server checksum function is returning the same value for these two different input values?

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(2792,2847), 2792+2847 » **42399**,5639

SELECT CHECKSUM(2716,3167), 2716+3167 » **42399**,5883
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the docs [CHECKSUM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) docs it indicates that there is the possibility of duplicates and to use [HASHBYTES (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. There seems to be a problem with decimals and CheckSum().
Solved it by casting all columns used in my checksum() to varchar

E.g.
instead of: `select checksum(columnA) from dbo.Table`
use: `select checksum(cast(columnA as varchar)) from dbo.Table`

`SELECT CHECKSUM(CAST(2792 AS VARCHAR), CAST(2847 AS VARCHAR)), 2792+2847` >> -1228994846 , 5639

`SELECT CHECKSUM(CAST(2716 AS VARCHAR), CAST(3167 AS VARCHAR)), 2716+3167` >> 1320541154, 5883